# Parse server errors - cannot find module

Tags: git, heroku, npm, parse-server

I am unable to update files on my Parse Server hosted on heroku as a result of trying to firstly update the server version, then trying to fix an issue that arose from attempting the update.

I wanted to update my Parse Server so that queries would have a limit of 1000 object instead of 100.

I tried a few things to do this including updating my package.json file from `"parse-server": "^2.2.25"` to `"parse-server": "^2.4.2"` then running npm install. I then tried `"parse-server": "git+https://github.com/JulienKode/parse-server.git"` and ran npm install but this also didn't increase query results.

Following this I wanted to make a change to my Cloud Code. I updated my cloud code file then added the changes to my server and ran `'git push heroku master'`. At this point I got the error cannot find module 'parse-server' and the app would crash.

In an attempt to fix this cloned the server files from a working version to my local git and have tried to update from this new git repository however I get the following error:

```
2017-06-12T21:41:29.513261+00:00 app[web.1]: > parse-server-example@1.4.0 start /app
2017-06-12T21:41:29.513261+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2017-06-12T21:41:29.513262+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-12T21:41:29.711423+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:487
2017-06-12T21:41:29.711425+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2017-06-12T21:41:29.711426+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2017-06-12T21:41:29.711427+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-12T21:41:29.711427+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'parse-server'
2017-06-12T21:41:29.711428+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
2017-06-12T21:41:29.711429+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
2017-06-12T21:41:29.711430+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
2017-06-12T21:41:29.711430+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
2017-06-12T21:41:29.711431+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:5:19)
2017-06-12T21:41:29.711431+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
2017-06-12T21:41:29.711432+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
2017-06-12T21:41:29.711433+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
2017-06-12T21:41:29.711433+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
2017-06-12T21:41:29.711434+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
2017-06-12T21:41:29.723006+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-06-12T21:41:29.723156+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2017-06-12T21:41:29.723291+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! parse-server-example@1.4.0 start: `node index.js`
2017-06-12T21:41:29.723375+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-06-12T21:41:29.723468+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-06-12T21:41:29.723554+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the parse-server-example@1.4.0 start script.
2017-06-12T21:41:29.723674+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-06-12T21:41:29.724625+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-12T21:41:29.724780+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2017-06-12T21:41:29.724850+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-06-12T21_41_29_720Z-debug.log
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I use AWS rather than Heroku, but there should be somewhere on Heroku to revert the server code to a previous deployment.

See here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#rollback

Comment: Thanks but I have already done this. I have rolled back to a working version, however the issue is that my local Git no longer matches the working deployment. I have tried cloning the working version to my local git, but I get errors when trying to re-push this to Heroku if I want to change cloud code for example.